# wordpress query filtering by custom-field, tag and category

Tags: custom-fields, wordpress

i have made this query to select posts from a WordPress blog filtering by Category, Tag and Custom Fields.

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE   wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'

AND     (       SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON ( wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id )
                WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
                AND     ( wp_terms.name = 'collaborazioni' && wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' ) 
                        ||
                        ( wp_terms.name = 'jammin' && wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag' )
            ) >= 1

AND     (       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta
                WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Product-code'
                AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'xxxxxx'
                ) >= 1
```

but i think that is a little heavy .. did you have some better solution ?

thanks, Pietro.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would you like to make shorter? It already looks shorten pretty well.

PS. You might want to use `{$wpdb->prefix}` instead of `wp_` in queries.

Comment: i don't know exactly what should be shorter, i was i asking if there is a bettere way to do this. Anyway i'll use $wpdb->prefix, thanks ;)

Comment: Then no, you have done maximum shortening there. And the $wpdb->prefix is something I'm using on all scripts that might run inside Wordpress installation where prefix is not the default wp_. Helpful little thingy.